# Overlapping accesses to frame

Tags: swift, uikit, func, overlapping

I put two functions in the code but it gives me this error:

Overlapping accesses to 'frame', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable

how can i solve?

```
import UIKit

extension UITabBarController {
    
    func hideTabBar() {
        var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
        frame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height + (frame?.size.height)!
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!
        })
    }

    func showTabBar() {
        var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
        frame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - (frame?.size.height)!
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!
        })
    }
    
}
```

Comment: add `var frame: CGRect?`, outside the function.

Comment: @OneCommentMan added, but now it gives me this error: Extensions must not contain stored properties

Comment: So the issue of your function is you accessing frame while you're trying to modify it. You can update your function to something like this. 

`func hideTabBar() {
        guard var frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else { return }

        let originY = self.view.frame.size.height + t.size.height

        frame.origin.y = originY

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame
        }
 }`

Comment: `t.size.height` to `frame.size.height`

Comment: @OneCommentMan if i put it inside the extension of UITabBarController it doesn't work

Comment: What you should be using is. `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed. It does work, extension UITabBarController {
    func hideTabBar() {
        guard var t = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else {
            return
        }

        let newOriginY = self.view.frame.size.height + t.size.height

        t.origin.y = newOriginY

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = t
        }

    }
}

Comment: i want it to go down after start navigation its a map navigation app

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be violating Swift’s exclusive access rules but I’m not smart enough to know why! But rewriting the methods to avoid all the optionals fixes the compiler errors:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func hideTabBar() {
        var frame = tabBar.frame
        frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height + frame.size.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tabBar.frame = frame
        })
    }

    func showTabBar() {
        var frame = tabBar.frame
        frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - frame.size.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tabBar.frame = frame
        })
    }
}
```

I don’t think adjusting the tab bar’s frame is very safe and you might have problems (anything that triggers a relayout of the tab bar controller could make the tab bar appear again). If you are hiding the tab bar when pushing a view controller on a navigation stack then this might be better: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed

Comment: if i put it inside the extension of UITabBarController it doesn't work

Comment: maybe I have to remove self?

Comment: Your original question didn’t say the code was in an extension of UITabBarController. I have updated my answer but am using a Playground on iPad so only compiled the code. I have not run it to test.